# What's the best practice of showing a lot of text inside Android Fragment

Tags: android, lists, text

What's the best way to present a lot of text to the user inside an Android Fragment?
I tried with `ExpandableListView` but since the individual items don't have a title, this is not the best solution I think.

I have items like the following:

- This is the first item and a lot of text
- This is the second item and even more text than the first item has had
- This is the third item and this also has lots and lots of text

There are about 20 items in total. How would you show this to the user in a nice and clean way?

Comment: It depends on the user, the content, and the objectives. (In other words: We need more info to be able to offer advice)

Comment: Why are you showing this list? Why would the user need to see all of this information all at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the items don't have a title, are they really items or just paragraphs of a even longer text? Will the user be interested in only one of those items or she might read more in sequence?

You could invent some titles yourself (even if they were "Item 1", "Item 2", etc), but the problem with the ExpandableListView in this case is that due to the amount of content exhibited the user will lose track of what lies before and after the selected item. If you go for the "select an item" approach, perhaps it will be better to simply present the longer text in a different scrollable view, on top of the item list (and thus, when the user goes back there will be the list positioned in the item she previously read).

However, if the user might read more than one of those "items" in a sequence, a better approach might be presenting all the text in a single scrollable view with items displayed as paragraphs in a text editor, for example. A search box might help in fiding desired content.

In that last approach, if you want to allow the user to quickly glance through extracts of items (say, just a few characters from the beginning of each paragraph), you could create an advanced search that presents a list of extracts in a different view; the selection of a specific extract would simply position the cursor in the correct paragraph in the previous all-text view.

Comment: those are some nice approaches thanks alot! I'll try them out to see what is the best match for me.

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Let us know how it goes. :)